# Good design for accessing subclass methods in a vector of abstract class objects

Tags: java, object, inheritance, vector, abstract-class

I am using a vector to store objects of `AnAbstractClass` superclass. The abstract class contains only two non-constructor methods:

```
public final String getName() {
    return name;
}

public abstract int getCost();
```

Within each subclass I created a `getCost`  method. Within `anotherClass` I have the vector of abstract class objects. In a method of `anotherClass` I am using a string that contains name, cost, and other data types that are specific to each of the multiple subclasses. I am currently accessing the vector to retrieve `name` and `cost` just fine.

However, when I try to access the other fields (ie: `getColor` or `getSize` that are specific to each subclass I run into the following compile error:

```
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method <mySubClassMethod>()
  location: class <MyAbstractClass>
```

How can I efficiently design a solution to this dilemma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access methods specific to a subclass you need to cast to the subclass.

Example:

```
Subclass foo = (Subclass) myAnAbstractClassInstance;
```

If you don't know what subclass you have, you can do a type check using instanceof

Example

```
// Subclass implements size and color, but superclass does not
if (foo instanceof Subclass) {
    Subclass foobar = (Subclass) foo;
    int size = foobar.size();
    String color = foobar.color();
}
```

Alternative solutions:
1. Make all subclasses provide all methods (even if they do nothing)
2. Make all subclasses provide a method that lets you know what methods they support

Comment: lmk if this doesn't answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Either add getColor and getSize to the abstract class, or if you want something totally dynamic, try having a method like getData() which returns a Map of name/value pairs.
If you need something even more dynamic, try using groovy instead of java. Then you can MetaProgram your way out of any dilemma!